# best way to transfer multi encoded characters over boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I want to transfer xml in single byte characters, but some of the values will be in unicode.
i.e.

```
<value>Unicode string</value>
```

I'm using boost::asio.

Comment: clarify your question please. What are you transferring... to where ? What the heck are you using boost::asio (an async io library) for and what does that have to do with what character encoding you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Network/Socket transfer => single byte encoding
XML => mostly UTF-8

Conclusion: convert everything to UTF-8 before pushing it to boost::asio.